# GPU fan incredible speed/loud after system bootup

Tags: gpu, fan

When my system boot up, fans in my GPU starting spin very fast / very loud. When I disable the driver, fans stopping or going to normal / previous set speed. Some days ago, I just dismount GPU from PC, again mount it, and fans worked good. Next day, boot up, and my PC want to fly out.

Yesterday when I played game, those fans just "stopping, starting" several times. I ran GPU-Z, fan speed 25(%) (displaying AfterBurner setting), fan speed in RPM 0, but sometimes flicking for random values (for ex. 11000).

Log file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1C_5nKC8-sqhw0cyNOXBfB8Wa8CtUoTLD

Now, I just playing game, and fans is quieter now. GPU-Z shows normally rpm. What is this?

GPU: Gigabyte 1070 Gaming G1
MOBO: B450-A Pro Max

Comment: Sounds like the fan’s RPM output could be broken. The fan control can’t work this way and falls back to maximum speed. Buuut that’s just a guess, never had a GPU fan fail myself.

Comment: Yea saw same info in other forums, and It could be it. Thinking about "bypass" this Fan Controller, connecting "stock" fans to mobo pwm, or eventually buy fans and stick them into gpu using ziptie (and connect to mobo pwm), but in my opinion stock fans to mobo will be best for my wallet. Or just looking for "non-stock" fans with good price and not shit-quality.